# Suggested parameter names for utility class function

Tags: java

During our internal code review process, my following code raised some eyebrows:

```
public class MySuperUtil {
    public static List<Long> updateAndSubtract(List<Long> first, List<Long> second) {
        List<Long> updated = updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds(second, first);
        Collection<?> difference = CollectionUtils.subtract(first, updated);
        return castCollectionToListUsingClass(difference, Long.class);
    }
```

(the castCollectionToListUsingClass is not related to this problem; it is from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2848268))

The main feedback is the names of parameters: `first` and `second`.

My reviewer suggests using names more informative to the caller, e.g. `inDB` instead of `first`, `inUI` instead of `second`.

My main points (of using `first` and `second`) are:

1. this is a Util class (although probably there will be only one occasion for it to be used)
2. this is similar to what [`CollectionUtils.substract()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) has

I guess my question really is: 
***what context do we use*** when naming those two parameters?

1. do we name them in the context of the **callee** `MySuperUtil` (thus 
   something like `first` and `second`, or probably `minuend` and `subtrahend`), **OR**,
2. do we name them in the context of the **caller** (thus `inDB` and `inUI`)?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just add it in the JavaDoc?

Comment: I am trying to follow what Robert Martin suggests in `Clean Code` in terms of comments.

Comment: But again, what is the issue with adding what first and second means in the JavaDoc? That should remove any doubt. Otherwise you could just do what they said; "inDB instead of first, inUI instead of second."

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. I would expect that your co-workers know a whole lot more about your code than we do, so my first suggestion would be to just go with what they suggest. I agree with them that variable names such as `first` and `second` are not good ones. What is your method used for? What is the omitted return statement?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg i've updated the function with return statement. this method provided by MySuperUtil takes 2 lists of Long (`a` and `b` for simplicity), and does some update, and then returns the list `a minus b`.

Comment: @Vipar ok i got your point there. please see my updated questions at the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Math.min()` and `java.util.Math.max()` use the variable names a and b.  `java.util.Comparator.compare()` uses variable names o1 and o2.  `java.util.Math.pow()` uses variable names a and b.  `CollectionUtils.substract()` uses variable names a and b.

I believe that this evidence favors the argument that the context of the variable names should be local to the callee (which is the code that must reference these names, after all), and that in simple circumstances where the arguments have no distinct identity, it is acceptable to use contextless names.

I'm not immediately convinced that this argument applies in the code you provided.

```
public static List<Long> updateAndSubtract(List<Long> first, List<Long> second) {
    List<Long> updated = updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds(second, first);
```

Why does the call to `updatePlaceholderWithLargestIds` reverse the order of the arguments?  If the order of the arguments is arbitrary, then they should be consistent.  If the order of the arguments is not arbitrary, then THAT context should be used to remind the next programmer why the arguments should be switched.

`inDB` and `inUI` are not good names here, but they do suggest that the contents of the two lists are not the same, and should be distinguished.  For example, if one of the Lists contains provisional ids, and the other contains permanent ids, then the variable names should reflect that distinction.

In that situation, I'd go one step further, and introduce a helper class just to clarify everything.

```
static class PlaceholderEditor {
    static PlaceholderEditor usingSource(List<Long> reference) {
        return new PlaceHolderEditor(reference);
    }

    private final List<Long> reference;

    PlaceholderEditor(List<Long> reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    List<Long> updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds(List<Long> source) {
        return OriginalImplementation.updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds(source,reference);
    }
}

public static List<Long> updateAndSubtract(List<Long> first, List<Long> second) {
    List<Long> updatedIds = PlaceholderEditor.usingSource(first).updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds(second);
```

The helper method here could simply forward to the existing implementation, as shown here, or you could refactor that work into the helper.

`usingSource` is an example of a factory method, used here to insulate the client from the details of the object creation (new object on the heap? object pulled from a pool? singleton?).  It's a common idiom in [Fluent Interfaces](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html), but not necessary -- `new PlaceholderEditor...` is better if it reduces confusion on your team.

If you sometimes updatePlaceholdersWithSomethingElse, then perhaps there is also a strategy object to be teased out.

Comment: I really like the idea of the helper class. A follow-up question: can you explain / provide a pointer to how to implement it? the best i can get is (using non-static methods): `new PlaceholderEditor().usingReference(first).replacePlaceholder(second);`. in other words, if the methods are static, what does `PlaceholderEditor.usingSource()` return?

Comment: Surprise!  I didn't limit myself to non-static methods :)  See revised answer

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public class MySuperUtil {
>     public static List<Long> updateAndSubtract(List<Long> first, List<Long> second) {
>         List<Long> updated = updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds(second, first);
>         Collection<?> difference = CollectionUtils.subtract(first, updated);
>         return castCollectionToListUsingClass(difference, Long.class);
>     }
> ```

My assessment of the code is that, as a Util method, it is poorly named too. The methods are not self-documenting.

I read `updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds`, and with two lists as inputs, where is the Id? What does 'updated' look like? I am at a loss.

What I can say is that there is some black-box function that does some update, but, does it manipulate the data in first, or second? Why is 'second' specified first? Why is it not: `updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds(first, second);`

Also, why does an `update*` function return a value, and not update something? it should be called `get*` or just `largestIds`. Or, does the function do both? Does it update values and also return values? Yuck!.

The `subtract` function. Does it subtract the first value from the second, or the other way around?

`castCollectionToListUsingClass` I presume this method has the signature:

```
public static <U> List<U> castCollectionToListUsingClass(Collection<?> collection, Class<U> clazz);
```

Why all the redundancy? That method name duplicates all the signature components. It is tautology. Also, why does it take a collection, and return a List? It should return a Collection too, or it should be parameterized too.... at minimum, just rename the method to something like (I like the word `coerce`):

```
public static <U> List<U> coerceMembers(Collection<?> collection, Class<U> clazz);
```

So, I would agree that naming is a concern in your code, but it extends beyond just your method.

Your method does not tell me what it does, and the code in the method does not help much either. The code in the method does not help me help you rename the method.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i've made the following changes: 1. rename castBlarg to `coerceElements` (i think `elements` is  more suitable than `Members`); 2. rename `updateBlarg` to `replaceBlarg` (yes, update _is_ confusing);

Comment: as for your comment for the logic in `updatePlaceholdersWithLargestIds` ... i agree its name does confuse readers. in my case, it's an awkward situation to reuse some existing code and build on top of it. personally i prefer the fluent interfaces from @VoiceOfUnreason's answer.